# C# WPF ошибка доступа из потока к RichTextBox.Document через Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.LineHeight = 2;
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("11111"))
        {
            Foreground = Brushes.White,
            Background = Brushes.Black
        });
        doc.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        rr(doc);

    }).Start();
}
private void rr(FlowDocument d)
{
    this.richtextbox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => {
    this.richtextbox1.Document = d;  }));
}
```

выдает ошибку:

> "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it."

тоже самое если попробовать `richtextbox1.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph)`.
А вот `richtextbox1.AppendText(text)` идет без проблем.

Comment: Вы создаёте контрол в потоке отличном от потока GUI, так нельзя делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали FlowDocument в одном потоке. А обращаетесь к нему в другом. Так делать не получится. Организуйте паттерн Builder(Строитель), пусть он занимается созданием FlowDocument но уже в основном потоке.

Comment: Если в функции с диспатчером создать FlowDocument и присвоить ему созданный FlowDocument, и затем уже присвоить его richedit, то ошибка возникнет именно в richedit, а не в FlowDocument. Значит проблемма не в созданном FlowDocument или я неправильно понял то, что мне пытаются сказать?

И буду очень благодарен если объясните для чайника подробнее про решение проблемы с помощью паттерна Builder. Если не примером, то хотя бы в словах, но более подробно... а то я все ето слишком абстракно понимаю и не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: Вам нужно создать FlowDocument в основном потоке. Это можно сделать без Строителя, но с ним код будет чище. Идея состоит в том, чтоб в метод rr передавать не уже готовый FlowDocument, а данные необходимые для его создания. Так же можно передать в метод уже инстанс Строиля. А построить FlowDocument уже в основном потоке под Dispatcher.Invoke.

Всё зависит от конкретной задачи. Тут она не раскрыта и код выглядит как какой-то костыль. Для чего вам вообще отдельный поток?